# Time complexity of the depth-first search in linear time

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity, complexity-theory, graph-algorithm, depth-first-search

I confused with time complexity of the below algorithm is it O(V) or O(V+E)?

```
DFS(G,s,t):


vis[s] = true
        if s == t
            vis[s] = false, return 1
        cont = 0
        for v is adj(s)
            if vis[v] == false
                cont = cont + DFS(G,s,t)
        vis[s] = false
        return cont
```

Comment: What is `n` and `m`?

Comment: your program never ends, always calling DFS(G,s,t)

Comment: @JKLM `s` and `t` are apparently the source and destination, which have nothing to do with the time complexity. When dealing with graph problems, the time complexity is typically dependent on the number vertices (V), and the number of edges (E) in the graph.

Comment: oops sorry for the confusion I have updated the question

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When studying graph complexity theory, it is easier sometimes to think of "how many times do I process each edge/vertex" over how many times does this loop run. This is because loops in graphs have variable length, and with the recurrences things just get messy.

Ultimately, in the DFS algorithm, you will have to check what is at the other end of every edge, and decide whether to visit the vertex or not. You will do this exactly once and only once for each edge. So, you are obliged to consider each edge.

Since each vertex is also being considered (visited) exactly once, then this yields an O(V+E) complexity.